# Change the default editor for files opened in the terminal? (e.g. set it to TextEdit/Coda/Textmate)

Tags: macos, terminal, text-editor

Is there a way to make files opened for editing in the terminal open in Textedit instead?

For example, where a command might open a file for editing (like `git commit`), instead of opening that file in vim or emacs, it would open in Textedit (or perhaps another text editing application of your choosing, such as Coda or Sublime).

And as a bonus question, is there any way to specifically configure git to automatically open the file created after running `git commit` in an editor from the applications directory?

Comment: Yes, I am using OSX (10.6.4).

Comment: Best solution I found is using `duti` -> http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/123954/58507

Comment: for mac os 10.10+ above solutions won't work. Try this
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123833/replace-text-edit-as-the-default-text-editor/220496#220496

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Most programs will check the `$EDITOR` environment variable, so you can set that to the path of TextEdit in your bashrc. Git will use this as well.

#### How to do this:

- Add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:
  `export EDITOR="/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit"`
- or just type the following command into your Terminal:
  `echo "export EDITOR=\"/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit\"" >> ~/.bashrc`

If you are using zsh, use `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Perfect, this does it. I also ran this command to make sure git works the way I would expect it to. This `git config --global --unset-all core.editor` then `git config --global --add core.editor "open -W -n"`.

Comment: Are you using a different shell?

Comment: in my case, I am using `zsh` so obviously I need to update the `.zshrc` config file.

Comment: use quotes if the path to your editor has spaces, e.g.  


`"echo "export EDITOR=\"/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl\"" >> ~/.bashrc"`  


And you may have to reload your .bashrc with:
`source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks, I've set nano editor as default by this. Here's how to add it to OSX: [http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021017065800302](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021017065800302)

Comment: Mars Redwyne, I tried the quotation marks for spaces (export EDITOR=/Applications/Sublime\"Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\"Text), as well as just a slash with the space (export EDITOR=/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text), but neither worked, even after running the source command. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Michelle Glauser your quotes should go like EDITOR="/Applications/.../Sublime Text" or whatever. Across the entire EDITOR export, not just something inside it. (A whole month late on this response... oops)

Answer (score 50):

For anyone coming here in 2018 using iTerm:

- go to iTerm -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Semantic History
- from the dropdown, choose Open with Editor and from the right dropdown choose your editor of choice

For anyone coming here in 2022 and using iTerm2:

iTerm2 moved some things around so now it's found under

- iTerm -> Settings -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Semantic History

Answer (score 33):

Use `git config --global core.editor mate -w` or `git config --global core.editor open` as @dmckee suggests in the comments.

Reference: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: ...and setting it to use `open` means that you automatically get the finder default. So changes in the finder are propagated naturally.

Comment: `open` uses Launch Services to determine the file type, mostly based on its extension.  If the file has an unknown extension, it'll fail to open the file.  Generally, your CLI editor should be something that assumes text files...

Comment: Some (very) explicit instructions would be very helpful...the reference is extremely terse.

Comment: @Diogenes: See my answer on a different post if you still need more explicit help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435246/trouble-on-setting-the-git-core-editor/6435291#6435291

Comment: Better be `git config --global core.editor "open -W"` (otherwise you'll get a `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.` error).

Comment: I agree with @Gordon Davisson. Setting your editor to something that is not a text editor is incorrect.

Answer (score 22):

## For OS X and Sublime Text

Make [`subl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199581/opening-sublime-text-on-command-line-as-subl-on-mac-os) available.

Put this in `~/.bash_profile`

```
[[ -s ~/.bashrc ]] && source ~/.bashrc
```

Put this in `~/.bashrc`

```
export EDITOR=subl
```

Comment: I found that this does not work correctly with `chsh`.  The file opens, but any changes are lost.  I had to use `chsh -s /bin/zsh` to switch shells manually.

Answer (score 6):

Set your editor to point to this program:

```
/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

With SVN, you should set `SVN_EDITOR` environment variable to:

```
$ export SVN_EDITOR=/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
```

And then, when you try committing something, TextEdit will launch.

Comment: I'd prefer to use `/usr/bin/open`, because that will use the finder default *whatever* you set it to.

Comment: How would you do the same for git?

Comment: The first like is just setting EDITOR= to that, but what do I type for the second line?

Answer (score 1):

For Sublime Text 3:

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add '{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.sublimetext.3;}'
```

See *[Set TextMate as the default text editor on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370584/set-textmate-as-the-default-text-editor-on-mac-os-x/22141204#22141204)* for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the editor to work with git operations, setting the `$EDITOR` environment variable may not be enough, at least not in the case of Sublime - e.g. if you want to rebase, it will just say that the rebase was successful, but you won't have a chance to edit the file in any way, git will just close it straight away:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.
```

If you want Sublime to work correctly with git, you should configure it using:

```
git config --global core.editor "sublime -n -w"
```

I came here looking for this and found the solution [in this gist on github](https://gist.github.com/geekmanager/9939cf67598efd409bc7).

Answer (score 0):

make Sublime Text 3 your default text editor: (Restart required)

```
defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers -array-add "{LSHandlerContentType=public.plain-text;LSHandlerRoleAll=com.sublimetext.3;}"
```

make sublime then your default git text editor
`git config --global core.editor "subl -W"`