# git svn dcommit bug id

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn, git-svn, issue-tracking

One of the new features of SVN is issue tracker integration. These let you add commit hooks to make SVN parse log messages for bug or issue numbers, and relate them to your issue tracking system.

[image]

I'm using git-svn to work with SVN through git.
Is three any possibilitty to make commits with bug id, using

```
git svn dcommit
```

? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that the text box is doing is doing is appending `<newline>Issue: %BUGID%` to the end of the commit message. You should be able to do this as part of the `git commit`. Each commit to Git is an individual commit to SVN, all dcommit does is push those commits to SVN. For example:

```
git commit -F- <<EOF
Fixing issue in blah blah blah because of blah blah.
Issue: 1234
EOF
//Any more commits...
git svn dcommit
```

You can read [Add line break to git commit -m from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-command-line) for more information about git commits with line breaks.