# How to include newline characters in git tag messages

Tags: git

When I tag versioned code in git, I like using bullet points in the tag message.

This can easily be done with annotated tags:

```
git tag -a v1.0.0

* Change number 1
* Change number 2
#
# Write a tag message
#
```

However, if I attempt the same tag with the -m option, the tag message is not what I expect:

```
git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "* Change number 1\n* Change number 2"

git show v1.0.0

...

* Change number 1\n* Change number 2
....
```

The '\n' was interpreted literally as the characters '\' and 'n' instead of a newline. I want to use the `-m` option so that I can automate the tagging process.

Is there any way to include actual newline characters using `git tag` with the `-m` option?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The closest solution I found is to use multiple `-m` options, one for each line. For example:

```
git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "* Change number 1" -m "* Change number 2"
```

from [git-tag man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-tag):

```
-m <msg>
   Use the given tag message (instead of prompting). If multiple
   -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate
   paragraphs. (...)
```

**UPDATE**: Check ["Add line break to git commit -m from command line"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-command-line) for more shell-based solutions.

Comment: Good answer. Oh the hidden treasures that can be found in the man pages. Thanks, Aziz!

Comment: This will put extra newlines between the messages, which may not be desirable.

Comment: My command: `git tag -a v1.1.0 -m "+ added highlight syntax for regular expressions in find and replace consoles," -m "+ added instructions about customization some graphic parameters for Windows 10 users."`. [**Result**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaSublime/releases/tag/v1.1.0). What I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Help for me: `tag -a st3-1.1.0 -m "Version 1.1.0" -m "+ added highlight syntax for regular expressions in find and replace consoles," -m "+ added instructions about customization some graphic parameters for Windows 10 users."`. [**Result**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaSublime/releases/tag/st3-1.1.0). Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Best solution is to write your commit and tag messages right from your default code editor.

- Use command `git tag -a v1.0.0` and hit enter. **Don't write `-m`**
- It will open up your default code editor, write message, save and close the file.
- Command line will be resumed.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative would be to put the formatted message in a (temporary) file and use `git tag -F <filename> <tag>` to read the message from that file.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using a unix shell, your syntax for newline is wrong.

```
git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "* Change number 1
* Change number 2"
```

should work.

Comment: What about `git tag -a v1.0.0 -m $'* Change number1\n* Change number 2'` ?

Comment: @DamienFlament That works as well, at least in bash.  Although I just tried my answer's syntax in csh, and it doesn't work there, so "unix shell" isn't accurate for my answer either :P