# Add line break to git commit -m from command line on Windows

Tags: windows, git

My company has a policy that all checkins to a particular project must follow a specific multi-line template for git commits. How can I most simply create a single commit message that has multiple lines from the command line in Windows?

<sub>*This is almost exactly a duplicate of* "[Add line break to git commit -m from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-command-line)" *except that this question is specific to Windows/cmd.exe, while that question is related to bash.*</sub>

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either create a file that contains your commit message in the right format and use `git commit -F <message_file>`, after which you can continually edit and reuse that same file, or create a template file and use `git commit -t <template_file>` to open your editor with the pre-cooked template to be filled in. The second option can be made permanent by setting the `commit.template` configuration variable, so you don't need to use the `-t ...` bit on every commit. See the `git commit` manual page (`git help commit`, if your `git` is installed correctly, or search online) for more information.

Answer (score 16):

You can create multiline commit message like this:

```
C:\> git commit -m "Line 1"^
More?
More? "Line 2"^
More?
More? "Line 3"
```

Note, that the circumflex character is only on odd lines.

Comment: doesn't work to input an empty line between message title, body and footer

Comment: I like this answer anyway :)

Answer (score 9):

```bash
git commit -m "Subject" -m "Description..."
```

> `-m <msg>`,
> `--message=<msg>`
> Use the given `<msg>` as the commit message. If multiple `-m` options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.
>
> The `-m` option is mutually exclusive with `-c`, `-C`, and `-F`.
> Source: [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit)

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 2):

You can also use interactive rebase and then reword for editing the commit's message.

Type `git commit -m "doesnt really matter whats here"` and then `git rebase -i HEAD~1`, replace `pick` with `r` or `reword`, save and then edit the message.

Comment: This is much easier than the accepted answer! Though, instead of an interactive rebase, you could save a step and use `git commit --amend`.

Comment: Sure! But this will work only for latest commit, rebase works for any! :)