# Git commit -m with multiple line

Tags: git

How do I produce a multiline comment in my git commit using -m

```
$ git commit -m "This change is for blah"
$ git commit -m "This change is for blah\nAnd also for this blah"
```

The second line, the `\n` doesn't produce a multiline comment

I'm using Mac terminal, not sure if that matter.

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423751/how-to-do-a-multiline-commit-message-in-git

Comment: `git commit` doesn't do any processing of the argument to `-m`; it's just a single string. Any method of embedding newline characters in that string will depend on how you specify the argument.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add line break to 'git commit -m' from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many environments (MacOS included) you can just hit enter to end the first line, as long as the quotes for the message are still open.

```
git commit -m "this is
a multiline
message"
```

Another option is to compose the message in a file and use `-F`.  (This is a more scriptable alternative to letting a text editor open for the commit message.)

The "multiple `-m` option' approach others are suggesting kinda-sorta works, but puts blank lines between the messages in my tests.

Comment: Using `-m` more than once is documented to create separate *paragraphs* in the commit message, not just separate lines, hence the blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you just use

```
git commit
```

It will open your editor and allow you to add more complex commit messages.

If you use

```
git commit -m "This is for blah" -m "This is more text"
```

it should commit several lines of text.

Comment: Multiple uses of `-m` will commit several *paragraphs*, not just several lines.

Comment: @chepner that's usually desired, as the convention is to have a blank line after the summary line and the summary line should be a single line and on the shorter side.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `--file` instead of `-m`. You can prepare message in a file and then commit like this:

```
git commit --file ~/proj/commit-message
```

It may be convenient to have a persistent message file (`commit-message`) in the starting directory of your projects (`~/proj`), this allows to use the same command repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your shell, most shells have a process-C-escapes marker. bash and I think many others use `$''`.

```
git commit -m subject -m $'this\nhas\nexplicit\nlinebreaks'
```

Just a note, `git log` can do word wrapping for you anyway, try

```
git log --pretty='%h%+w(76,6,9)%B'
```

for starters.