# Jenkins shell string quotation replacement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job with an execute shell box. In the execute shell I use bash instead of dash (sh). In the execute shell I have strings which are supposed to be interpreted as they contain escape sequences (in this case the new line: `\n`), so here is an example execute shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x #echo on
git fetch
...

git commit -m "Merging $DEVELOPEMENTBRANCH into $INITIALBRANCH\n\nThis is an example second paragraph."
...
```

My problem here is that the script block is interpreted/replaced by Jenkins in a way that it changes its behavior, to be specific it replaces the variables and replaces the double quotes with single quotes so in the console output it looks like this:

```
[4] $ /bin/bash /tmp/hudson7542128982632971668.sh
+ git fetch
...

+ git commit -m 'Merging my_feature into develop\n\nThis is an example second paragraph'
...
```

But in this way the `\n` part won't be interpreted because of the single quotes. What is the trick here? I want to preserve the double quotes or at least interpret the `\n` sequences.

Comment: Riska, can you please try with "\"Merging $DEVELOPEMENTBRANCH into $INITIALBRANCH\n\nThis is an example second paragraph.\"" ?

Comment: It's not working as it becomes: '"Merging my_feature into develop\n\nThis is an example second paragraph"'. As the single quotes are outside the result will be the same (with an extra pair of double quotes around the message)

Comment: For multi-line `git` commit msg have you tried following answers from http://stackoverflow.com/a/5064653/6128602?

Comment: Actually, I just used the git commit as a sample command. I use several similar commands with the very same issue and I needed a universal solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git commit -m "A multi-line\n\ncommit message"` will not produce a multi-line
commit message anyway. The commit message will be, literally, `A multi-line\n\ncommit message`.
Double-quotes do not cause `bash` to interpret `printf` escape-sequences.

To get a multi-line commit-message you need:

```
git commit -m "`printf \"A multi-line\n\ncommit message\"`"
```

This works fine in a Jenkins shell step.

Comment: If the shell is bash and not `/bin/sh`, one could avoid the performance overhead of the command substitution by using `git commit -m $'A multi-line\n\ncommit message'`.