# Jenkins shell script execution not working with multi-line double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

This is the script that is in my Jenkins build step:

```
echo "
echo \"==== Tagging this version ====\"
git checkout master
git pull
git tag -a $projectVersion -m \"version $projectVersion\"
git push origin $projectVersion

echo \"==== Cleaning up merged branches ====\"
git branch -r --merged | grep -v \\* | grep -v master | grep -v dmz | grep -v develop | while read line; do git push origin :\${line//origin\\//}; done

echo \"==== Merging release changes into develop and dmz ====\"
git checkout develop
git pull
git merge master
git push origin develop
git checkout dmz
git pull
git merge develop
git push origin dmz
git checkout master
"
```

The first `echo "` and the last `"` are trying to spit out whats in the middle as instructions to be run manually, but the `$projectVersion` variable substituted in. If I copy that code and paste it into my terminal it runs and prints fine. However, Jenkins is doing something funny with double quote multi-line strings, because the build keeps failing with this:

```
19:31:30 echo 
19:31:30 "==== Tagging this version ===="
19:31:30 Switched to a new branch 'master'
19:31:30 Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
19:31:31 Already up-to-date.
19:31:31 fatal: Failed to resolve '1.0.3"' as a valid ref.
19:31:31 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

It looks like it is completely ignoring the `"` right after the first `echo` which it should **not** be doing.

I read in multiple places that I need to use `printf` inside ``` `` ```, *inside* an `echo ""` statement, so I tried that but got lost with trying to escape everything:

```
echo "`printf \"echo \\"==== Tagging this version ====\\"\ngit checkout master\ngit pull\ngit tag -a $projectVersion -m \\"version $projectVersion\\"\ngit push origin $projectVersion\n\necho \\"==== Cleaning up merged branches ====\\"\ngit branch -r --merged | grep -v \\\* | grep -v master | grep -v dmz | grep -v develop | while read line; do git push origin :\\${line//origin\\\//}; done\n\necho \\"==== Merging release changes into develop and dmz ====\\"\ngit checkout develop\ngit pull\ngit merge master\ngit push origin develop\ngit checkout dmz\ngit pull\ngit merge develop\ngit push origin dmz\ngit checkout master\\"`"
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Jenkins, but try putting a backslash at the end of each line.

Comment: @Barmar Good thought, but sadly that didn't work. All I get as a result is: `20:00:35 /var/appl/jenkins/RC/tmp/hudson2707907294587456168.sh: line 35: unexpected EOF while looking for matching '"'`

Comment: This is a job for a heredoc.

Comment: though all the stray backslashes next to your literal quotes make it harder. Do you have a version from before you added them?

Comment: BTW, whatever source told you to use printf inside a command substitution was utter garbage. If it was a SO answer, could you please link it?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593485/jenkins-shell-string-quotation-replacement) it is. However, before passing judgement, just know that the problem was slightly different in that context and so the solution might be appropriate for that one even if it weren't for mine.

Comment: Ahh -- so the "inside an echo statement" part isn't taken from the remote answer. Big difference there; `echo "$(foo)"` is functionally equivalent to just running `foo`, except a lot slower (unless `foo` changes its behavior on whether output is to a TTY or some other odd corner cases, but in general).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not reading things to completion and instead just trying things out for a quick and dirty solution until an internal org issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in my carelessness, it turns out in a line (that is not shown) before the first line in the example did not have a closing quote. I closed it and everything worked as expected.

With that said, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943859/1902896) answer is worth a read as it's a way better way of doing what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

#### Approach One: Heredocs

If you want to dump a block of content to stdout, a heredoc is the right tool for the job. This one assumes you want `$projectVersion` replaced with that variable's value (though note that doing such replacement in a code-generation context generally constitutes a security hazard).

```
# generate a shell-quoted version of $projectVersion
# this is safe to use, and *must only be used*, in an unquoted context.
printf -v projectVersion_q '%q' "$projectVersion"

cat <<EOF
echo "==== Tagging this version ===="
git checkout master
git pull
git tag -a $projectVersion_q -m "version "$projectVersion_q
git push origin $projectVersion_q

echo "==== Cleaning up merged branches ===="
git branch -r --merged | while read -r line; do
  case \$line in
    [*]|master|dmz|develop) continue ;;
    *) branch=\${line#origin/}; git push origin ":\$branch";;
  esac
done

echo "==== Merging release changes into develop and dmz ===="
git checkout develop
git pull
git merge master
git push origin develop
git checkout dmz
git pull
git merge develop
git push origin dmz
git checkout master
EOF
```

#### Approach Two: One Big `printf`

```
printf -v projectVersion_q '%q' "$projectVersion"

# Generate an array, one element per line, individually quoted as appropriate for each
lines=(
  'echo "==== Tagging this version ===="'
  'git checkout master'
  'git pull'
  "git tag -a $projectVersion_q -m 'version '$projectVersion_q"
  "git push origin $projectVersion_q"
  ''
  'echo "==== Cleaning up merged branches ===="'
  'git branch -r --merged | while read -r line; do'
  '  case $line in'
  '    [*]|master|dmz|develop) continue ;;'
  '    *) branch=${line#origin/}; git push origin ":$branch";;'
  '  esac'
  'done'
  ''
  'echo "==== Merging release changes into develop and dmz ===="'
  'git checkout develop'
  'git pull'
  'git merge master'
  'git push origin develop'
  'git checkout dmz'
  'git pull'
  'git merge develop'
  'git push origin dmz'
  'git checkout master'
)
printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

Comment: Yeah, from the outside it looks like a hazard, but the generated code is being run by me, it's not being run automatically, and the variable is also being set by me.

Comment: Not being set by something like a git tag that someone other than you could potentially create? (Or is this a project in which you're the only person with commit access?)

Comment: I and one other person on my team, who could also be running this if he runs the build instead.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm used to teams-of-hundreds, and needing to worry about minimizing the damage someone who's stolen a developer's credentials can do. (If you're signing commits, maybe an attacker can't add a new commit without a hardware private-key token, but maybe they *can* create an arbitrarily-named tag pointing to an existing commit... y'know, that kind of paranoia).

Comment: Quick meta question: turns out the the reason the double quote madness was happening was because of my carelessness in forgetting a closing double quote in an earlier line. Do I state that and answer my own question (I would definitely give props to your well-crafted answer) or do I just mark this one as accepted and note my findings in a comment? Or something else?

Comment: Your call, no objection here either way.

Answer (score 0):

If the first `echo` is a groovy echo (i.e. not running in the shell), then you just need to do triple double quotes to make this work:

echo """
print a whole
bunch of multiline stuff
in here
"""