# Saving a commit message in -v mode

Tags: git

When saving a one-liner commit I usually type the following, followed by hitting enter:

```
git commit -m "Some interesting changes"
```

But how do I save a git commit message when entering verbose mode like this:

```
git commit -v
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add line break to 'git commit -m' from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-the-command-line)

Comment: `git commit` without `-m/-F` opens a text editor, and you can enter here any message you want.