# Simplest way to insert a new line in a bash string

Tags: bash

I have a bash string that looks like this:

```
string="This is the first line.
This is the second line"
```

I would like to convert this into a git commit message, so I need to insert a blank line after the first line to make it the commit title, and the second line the commit body, so that the expansion looks like this:

```
This is the first line.

This is the second line
```

What is the simplest way to achieve this in bash?

Comment: If you're getting the above string as an output of the variable, then it actually has newlines present

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064563/add-line-break-to-git-commit-m-from-the-command-line)? (There are few answers here depending on your need)

Comment: @JNevill, I'm not sure it's a duplicate; I guess OP wants a _blank_ line between first and second line (not too sure, though). Tri Nguyen, can you confirm you want a blank line between the two?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I can't see how that would make a difference. Each of those answers could be slightly massaged to include a second blank line between the two strings.

Comment: @JNevill: (I don't know, I'm just wild guessing here): maybe OP has this string already, and wants to insert a blank line between the first line and the rest of the string? (again, I really don't know, just guessing).

Comment: @JNevill, I agree this is not a duplicate of the git commit question.  OP says he has a *bash* string already and wants to insert a new line.  To boot, there is no git tag. I believe he was just giving context.

Comment: So this question is really more like a `tr '\n', '\n\n'` type of thing and we are assuming this "String in bash" is a variable holding two lines? I would suggest voting to reopen (I can vote, but can't reopen on my own), but it may just get closed again as unclear.

Comment: @JNevill: no problems, we can reopen it if needed; I'd just like to have OP's confirmation `:)`. (and then we might slightly edit the question to make it clearer).

Comment: THanks. @BillDoughty and gniourf are correct. This is not a git commit question. I already have the string in bash. I'm just looking to insert the blank line. The git commit is for context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do (it replaces the first newline character found by two consecutive newline characters):

```
string="This is the first line.
This is the second line"
new_string=${string/$'\n'/$'\n\n'}
echo "$new_string"
```

The `${var/pattern/replacement}` is a [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion); it expands to the expansion of `var` where the first occurrence of `pattern` is replaced by `replacement`.

The `$'...'` is known as [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) and will allow escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks. What's the purpose of `$` in the regex?

Comment: @TriNguyen: added explanation and references to address that.