# cannot add commit and push code from macs terminal to github

Tags: github

does anyone know how to push code to Github from the terminal? 
I do the `git add` . but when i do the `git commit` it shows many errors can anyone show me the right way?

Comment: can you post the error message

Comment: its asks for the commit message but when i type it and press enter it just goes to a new line how can i actually commit the code?

Comment: `git commit -m "commit message"` are you using the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Only [`git commit --allow-empty-message`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---allow-empty-message) would make a commit without you having to enter a message.
But that is not a good practice.

[`git commit -m "<msg>"`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--mltmsggt) will Use the given `<msg>` as the commit message.
As seen in "[Add line break to 'git commit -m' from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5064563/6309)", multiple `-m` means multiple lines to your commit message.

```
git commit -m "My head line" -m "My content line."
```