# Trouble on setting the git 'core.editor'

Tags: git, macos, editor, warnings, osx-snow-leopard

I am trying to set git on my *Mac Os Snow Leopard 10.6.7* but I made some errors on doing that...

At this time I have the following *warning*:

```
$ git config --global core.editor
EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
error: More than one value for the key core.editor: mate
$ git config --global core.editor open
warning: core.editor has multiple values
```

How can I solve that? And, mostly, how can I set the `core.editor` to TextEdit and make it works?

P.S.: I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539594/is-there-a-way-to-make-textedit-the-default-editor-for-text-files-opened-in-the-t).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the environment variable EDITOR to point to mate. In your `.bash_profile` add the following:

```
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

and re-start your terminal session, or source the `.bash_profile`.

As for your error message:

```
error: More than one value for the key core.editor: mate
```

it means you've added multiple core.editor lines in your .gitconfig.

Use mate `~/.gitconfig` to modify your `.gitconfig` and remove the extra lines, or if you don't mind unsetting all of them use:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
```

Then use

```
git config --global --add core.editor "/usr/local/bin/mate -w"
```

then you can leave `$EDITOR` set to what it was previously set to.

---

If `mate` is not located in `/usr/local/bin` find where it is first by using `type mate` (in bash, not sure about other shells)

---

Since you want to use `open` as your `$GIT_EDITOR` you will need the following:

```
-W  Causes open to wait until the applications it opens (or that were already open) have exited.  Use with the -n flag to allow open to function as an appropriate app for the $EDITOR environment variable.

-n  Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running.
```

This will work for that:

```
 git config --global --unset-all core.editor
 git config --global --add core.editor "open -W -n"
```

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem with double 'core.editor' statement in the '.gitconfig' file (thanks)... but now, if I run the command 'git commit -a' I get the following message: "Aborting commit due to empty commit message.". I set '$ git config --global core.editor open'.

Comment: open the command returns immediately after starting the program that is appropriate for the type, what you need to do is start open with the -W and -n parameters. (See `man open` for more information on what they do). Added the commands to do so in my original post.

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me:

```
git config --global core.editor "open -a 'Sublime Text 2' -nW"
```

Using Mac OSX 10.7.4 and Sublime Text 2 Build 2181

Note:

I have subl as an alias:

```
alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, here's how I solved it:

1) Run in Terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

This adds a `subl` alias to `/usr/local/bin/` pointing to Sublime Text 3 app’s binary file. Now running `subl` in Terminal will launch Sublime Text 3 app.

2) Run in Terminal:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

This adds `editor = subl -n -w` to the `[core]` section of the `~/.gitconfig` file. Now running `git commit` in Terminal will launch Sublime Text 3 app (`subl`) in a new window (`-n`), and the command line will wait (`-w`) until the commit message is saved.

Official Sublime Text 3 doc: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html

Answer (score 1):

To get this working for win7, open the .gitconfig file in c:/users/username/ folder and add the following line with --wait option outside the double quotes.

```
[core]
  editor = 'F:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' --wait
```

Hope its helpful to win7 users