# Minor Git Issue - Changing Default Editor

Tags: git, textmate, commit, git-config

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)
>   [Trouble on setting the git 'core.editor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435246/trouble-on-setting-the-git-core-editor)

I'm trying to change my default git text editor to TextMate, such that forgetting the -m tag on a commit will bring me into TextMate and not vi.  I have

```
[core]
editor = mate -w
```

in my ~/.gitconfig, but it still throws the following error at me:

```
error: cannot run TextMate: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor 'TextMate'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Fiddled around with various guides on how to set/unset the core editor, and couldn't really find anything that worked so I'm here for a pick-me-up.

Comment: @karlphillip: TextMate is on Mac

Comment: what is the output of `git config core.editor`?

Comment: To close voters: referenced duplicates address different stuff, this question is about a specific error

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more clear: I tried all of the relevant threads I found on SO, and none of them worked.  including the two that you linked above. 

    `git config core.editor: TextMate.`
    running `mate` opens up TextMate, as it should...`mate -w` functions precisely as expected.  I presume this is a simple routing problem, but since I'm not overly familiar with fixing such issues...

Comment: Furthermore: my ~/.bash_profile has: export EDITOR="/usr/bin/mate -w"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my answer in this question: [Trouble on setting the git 'core.editor'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435246/trouble-on-setting-the-git-core-editor/6435291#6435291)

---

Since you already have `$EDITOR` set up correctly, just remove the entries from git:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
```

now try a git commit again.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: See above comment for my clarifications.

Comment: @Nick Coelius: Try the command I have added above, just unset core.editor entirely since you have `$EDITOR` set.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I could've sworn I'd tried, and failed, to do that before, but I guess not.