# Revert Git Editor

Tags: git, text-editor, git-revert

I attempted to change the native code editor for Git, but I have done it unsuccessfully. Now, anytime I attempt to revert a commit, I get the following error:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... notepad++.exe -wl1: notepad++.exe: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'notepad++.exe -wl1'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I was wondering how I go about resetting or removing the attempted modification I made.

Comment: So is your question about *reverting commits* (a very specific thing in Git, using the `git revert` command), or is it about *updating your configuration settings?* If the latter, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/6459506/1256452

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the settings from the global and local configs:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
git config --unset-all core.editor
```

Default editor is `vim`, it's a bit hard to grasp it so you better set a different, more familiar editor. See

[How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits/)

and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+core.editor

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just find and fix an `editor` setting under `[core]` section in your `~/.gitconfig` (`C:\Users\<user>\.gitconfig`).

Comment: But how do I go about removing the entry I have there from hte command line, and return it to whatever its default would have been, had I not tried to change anything

Comment: You can open that file with your favourite editor and simply remove the lines.