# git: Aborting commit due to empty commit message (editor: atom)

Tags: macos, git, atom-editor

When I try to commit something, not using "-m", I get this message immedately.
I changed my default editor to atom with "-w" set, also tried "-W".

```
git config --global core.editor -w
```

Using vim, it works just fine...

I'm running OSX Yosemite.

So, how can I get this to work?

Edit: Atom opens properly, but the error message gets posted before it does.

Comment: When you use atom from the command line, to you have to add `&` to open the editor and prevent that process from blocking the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Atom Editor Git Integration](http://blog.atom.io/2014/03/13/git-integration.html) page, in the "Commit Editor" section states that you must pass the `--wait` flag as part of the editor command:

```
git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

Comment: Addendum: Changing two values (atom -w) into one ("atom --wait"):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435246/trouble-on-setting-the-git-core-editor/6435291#6435291