# Aborting commit due to empty commit message (editor = atom)

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, git-commit

Does anyone actually use atom for git commit messages here? I want to but I'm having this problem and have been sticking with git commit -m '....' . When I try to use atom, it opens atom and almost immediately i get this message from git bash:
 hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... Aborting commit due to empty commit message.

Comment: I know this question has been asked but I searched vigorously and nothing in there worked for me. I use atom v 1.2.9 and still nothing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git: Aborting commit due to empty commit message (editor: atom)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29274376/git-aborting-commit-due-to-empty-commit-message-editor-atom)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+atom+editor+Aborting+commit+due+to+empty+commit+message

Comment: eventually switched to sublime and now I'm wondering why I even bothered with atom in the first place

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have switched to SublimeText since your question, but for others:

Recent (April 2019) [`atom/atom` issue 19147](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/19147#issuecomment-482997065)

> set `[core] editor = atom --add --wait` instead.
>   `--add` will always open the new editor in the last-focused window.

The recent Atom/Git seem still have issue (a different one, meaning your original issue might have been solved):

- Atom : 1.36.0
- Electron: 2.0.18
- Chrome : 61.0.3163.100
- Node : 8.9.3

On Windows 10

[image]

> ### Expected behaviour
>
> When we finish a Git commit message edit in Atom, it should return to the original process (e.g.: shell command)
>
> ### Actual behaviour
>
> Not returning to the original process.
>   (Before v1.36.0, it used to return to the original process)
>
> ### Note
>
> The same behaviour happens with other Git commands like crafting interactive commit rebasing.
>   The same thing happens when a Git commit message editor opens in Atom in safe mode