# unable to write commit message using atom text editor

Tags: git, atom-editor

I am getting this error 
        `Aborting commit due to empty commit message`
when I use the `git commit` comand.

I have configured the atom editor using this code 
        `git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`

every time I run the command 'git commit' the atom code editor opens but in the terminal i get this error msg 
        Aborting commit due to empty commit message
I tried typing the commit msg and closed the editor but nothing is commited.

`atom --wait` , `atom -w` and `atom --add --wait` are not working it opens atom and immediately show next terminal prompt.

Comment: Are you saving the file before closing the editor?

Comment: yes. I save the file before closing but not working @ÁlvaroPérez

Comment: Could you check that --wait works in your machine? As i described in my answer.

Comment: Try [`atom --add --wait`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55853440/7976758)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this->  git commit -m "insert commit message here"

Comment: When he use this, atom won't open because this command with -m and "message" flag just commit with that message, no editor need to be opened.

Comment: I don't want to use `git commit -m` i want to write a commit message in atom code editor.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that *atom* is opening. I've tried this with VSC and Sublime and it worked but as you can see you were trying to commit with blank message.

1. Type `git commit`
2. Wait until atom open
3. Type your message.
4. *Save file* and *close editor*

In that situation you should see proper result of `git commit`

EDIT: To check that `--wait` flag works. Type in console `atom --wait` (or maybe your terminal accpet only `-w` flag, dunno)

If this flag works terminal prompt should appear **after** closing atom. If doesn't should act like without flag so when you type, it opens atom and **immediately** show next terminal prompt.

Comment: it's lookie the wait flag is not working properly. for both the commands `atom --wait` and `atom -w` it opens atom and immediately show next terminal prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Atom 1.25`. 
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1433#issuecomment-355721229

This should fix it.

Comment: I am using atom 1.38.2 in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling atom editor solved my issue.