# Adding a git commit message using vi on OS X

Tags: git, macos, vim, merge, vi

I'm learning using Git on an OS X Terminal. It seems really easy. But I can't handle just one problem: When I try to merge two branches, for example "myTestBranch" into "master" this program covers the terminal and shows me a new view where I should write the merge message. And then, I don't know how to do "Enter", save the merge message and then come back to the main terminal view where I can continue working.

Does anyone know, how does it work?

[image: What I see, when i try to merge]

Comment: That is the vi or vim editor. You can get out of it by typing `:q<enter>`. You either need to learn vi (which is admittedly on the more difficult side) or define `$EDITOR` to be something friendlier, such as nano.

Comment: That's what I said, either vi or vim. Either way, either learn how to use, or else set your shell environment to use a different editor using the `$EDITOR` variable. `nano` is very simple to use and helpfully shows you what ctrl-keys you can press to exit, save, etc.

Comment: You should also look at the `core.editor` configuration option in git config (e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435246/trouble-on-setting-the-git-core-editor)

Answer (score 54):

If you haven't change the default git's editor, that "new view" is the Vi program.

To save your commit message using Vi, follow the next steps:

1. Type `i`
2. Write your message
3. Type the `ESC` key
4. Type `:wq`
5. DONE! :D

Typing `:q`, step 4, is not enough beacuse just means **QUIT** without saving. That's why you need `:wq`, which means **WRITE** and **QUIT**.

You can write your commit message using your favourite editor(vim, emacs, etc.). To achieve this, you can use configuration parameter or environment variables, listed in order:

1. **GIT_EDITOR** environment variable
2. **core.editor** configuration option
3. **VISUAL** environment variable
4. **EDITOR** environment variable

Using the configuration option type something like this:

```
$git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

Or if you want to use enviroment variables, add something like this to your `.bash_profile`

```
$export GIT_EDITOR="PATH/TO/YOUR/EDITOR"
```

Answer (score 15):

By default Git will open Vim as editor.

You basically need to type 'I' to start editing. After that `ESC` and type `:q` to quit or `:w` to save the file. You can also combine them: `:wq` to save and exit Vim.

For more information about Vim check the [official documentation](http://www.vim.org/docs.php)

To change Vim for any other editor check the [Git Environment Variables](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) or older posts with a similar question:
[How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Comment: It's pretty quirky to learn but there [are games](http://vim-adventures.com/) that help.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot :)